# How can I rollback to iTunes 10?

Tags: itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I downgrade iTunes 11 to 10.7 in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73191/how-can-i-downgrade-itunes-11-to-10-7-in-mountain-lion)

I really miss iTunes DJ. Its all I use, and I'd like to roll back to iTunes 10.  I guess my Library has been upgraded (didn't see a notices) so I'm not hopeful, but does anyone have a suggestion?

I have a timemachine backup, but thats all.

(I've seen the worthy answer: [With iTunes DJ gone from iTunes 11, what's a good replacement solution?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73202/with-itunes-dj-gone-from-itunes-11-whats-a-good-replacement-solution), but I had a groove, and I want it back!)

Comment: Does the duplicate answer and question help or perhaps are you on windows and we should reopen this?

Comment: thanks @bmike, I've made peace with v11.. the awesomely detailed instructions at the linked post are too much for me to justify :) thanks for checking!