# How do I enable cover flow in iTunes 11?

Tags: itunes, music, windows

I just installed iTunes 11 and I cant seem to find any place to activate the cover flow.
Did they remove it? Can I re-enable it? If I can't, does anyone know of a way to downgrade with out uninstalling and re-installing?

EDIT: I am using `Windows XP` operating system.

Comment: Yes, cover flow is gone from iTunes 11. Sorry, Can't help with the downgrading

Comment: Downgrading iTunes 11: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73191/how-can-i-downgrade-itunes-11-to-10-7-in-mountain-lion

Comment: Feel free to tag this windows or Mac (and more importantly put that detail inside the text of your question) as the steps to revert each differ slightly.

Answer (score 3):

It's gone. You could perhaps look for a different program to browse your library or [revert to iTunes 10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73191/how-can-i-downgrade-itunes-11-to-10-7-in-mountain-lion).

Comment: Thank you, but i am using a Windows OS.

Comment: Now I know not to upgrade from iTunes 10, I guess.

Comment: @DvirLevy Hmm - I'll see if I can find instructions to downgrade iTunes on windows. Feel free to ask that and link here if you decide to go that way. I'll be sure to help promote that question so you could get an answer.